# Inbox preview through API?

Tags: marketing-cloud

Is there anyway to get an inbox preview through the api? This would be a great feature but didn't see mention of it in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.  I wish I had better news!

Good luck.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: It is a legitimate answer, it was a yes/no question.